# Cuda 10.2 and pytorch 1.5 – OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

Getting below issue when after installing cuda 10.2 and installing pytorch 1.5 ‘conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch’ . Any ideas how to fix this issue?

OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 import torch

~\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch_init_.py in
79 dlls = glob.glob(os.path.join(th_dll_path, ‘*.dll’))
80 for dll in dlls:
—> 81 ctypes.CDLL(dll)
82
83

~\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init_.py in init(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
362
363 if handle is None:
–> 364 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
365 else:
366 self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? You get that error when running the command?

Comment: Getting the error when I run 'import torch'

Comment: _Can you share the contents of the environment?_